# MongoDB use aggregation framework calculate differences after group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use MongoDB Aggregation in order to analyze data. Currently I've the following code:

```
db.events.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {codename: "IGNITION_ON"},
                    {codename: "IGNITION_OFF"}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                asset: 1,
                codename: 1,
                createdAt: 1,
                fuel: 1,
                odometer: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    asset: "$asset",
                    codename: "$codename",
                    day: { $dayOfYear: "$createdAt"}, 
                    year: { $year: "$createdAt" }
                },
                sumOdometer: {$sum: "$odometer"},
                sumFuel: {$sum: "$fuel"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

The code above retrieves the all ignitions on and off for all vehicles and calculates the sum of their odometer and fuel in one day. The problem is I need to obtain the following output, which is the difference of fuel and odometer (distance and consumption) for each vehicle in one day.

```
[
    {
        "asset" : ObjectId("540e5d8e44616e1c8b260000"), 
        "day" : 213, 
        "year" : 2014 
        "diffOdometer" : "5",
        "diffFuel" : "10"
    },
    ...
]
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Would "odometer" not be an incremental counter here? So sampled at points in time. And what of fuel? Is this a "current" level or a "consumed" level in a time period? There isn't enough explanation of the data here to be sure as to what works and what doesn't

Comment: Both are the current level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators in this case. These usually make sense after a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) unless you are absolutely sure that all documents are already in increasing date order:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "createdAt": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "asset": "$asset",
            "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$createdAt" },
            "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" }
        },
        "firstOdometer": { "$first": "$odometer" },
        "lastOdometer": { "$last": "$odometer" },
        "firstFuel": { "$first": "$fuel" },
        "lastFuel": { "$last": "$fuel" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "diffOdometer": { "$subtract": [ "$lastOdometer", "$firstOdometer" ] },
        "diffFuel": { "$subtract": [ "$lastFuel", "$firstFuel" ] }
    }}
])
```

And then of course work out the "differences" from "first" and "last" readings with the [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator after those values are obtained from grouping.

Not sure what relevance "ignition" on/off events have to your data sample, but it does not seem a logical point to "total" for in this case, but of course add any relevant [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) criteria as the first stage of your pipeline. Also noting that there is no specific advantage to placing a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline stage as you have. This does not "reduce" fields in the pipeline as you might think in this case. The pipeline "optimizer" will sort that out by only considering the fields specified in [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). And from the above it would do this from the start, so only the four fields used would be in the pipeline documents after a $match.

Of course this does not account for "re-fueling" and just takes the assumption that you begain with fuel and ended with fuel and the consumed is the difference. To take that into account you would presumably have a "re-fuel" event type, from which you could get a total of how much was put in. Like so:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "createdAt": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "asset": "$asset",
            "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$createdAt" },
            "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" }
        },
        "firstOdometer": { "$first": "$odometer" },
        "lastOdometer": { "$last": "$odometer" },
        "firstFuel": { "$first": "$fuel" },
        "lastFuel": { "$last": "$fuel" },
        "reFuelled": {
            "$sum": { "$cond": [ 
                { "$eq": [ "codename", "REFUEL" ] },
                "$filled",
                0
            ] }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "diffOdometer": { "$subtract": [ "$lastOdometer", "$firstOdometer" ] },
        "diffFuel": { 
            "$subtract": [ 
                "$lastFuel", 
                { "$add": [ "$firstFuel", "$reFuelled" ] }
            ] 
        }
    }}
])
```

Or something along those lines at any rate.

Short case is getting your "start" and "end" data and then applying the math to those points.